# WPF Path.RenderTransform databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, rendertransform

I'm able to bind a rectangle RotateTransform simply using the following. Which is drawn directly in a Grid.

```
<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ClockPosition}" />
</Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

With a Path no binding occurs. If I hard code the angle inline
it works fine. This is draw in a Grid within a Canvas.

```
<Path Name="ClockLine"
        Stroke="Green"
        StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="150,150"
                        EndPoint="150,40" />
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>

            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ClockPosition}" 
                                CenterX="150" CenterY="150" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
```

I though it may be some sort of a converter issue but both Rectangle and Path
are Shape objects. I know LineGeometry is a Geometry Object. Do I need a type conversion because of this? If so a sample or pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: That works. Are you sure you've set the ClockPosition correctly?

Comment: Just came to post and hang my head in shame... You can implement NotifyPropertyChanged all you like but if you don't add the INotifyPropertyChanged interface well.... boo me copy and pasted the code body and just forgot. This site is great by the way to debug Binding... Don't know how I lived without it. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/